# C# Microsoft.DirectX.DirectShow cause crash on load

Tags: c#, audio, directx

I am using Microsoft.DirectX.DirectShow to play 2 or more audio files at the same time.

I tried it in my computer with directx11 and it works fine.
but I also tried it in directx 10 and 9 and It crashed onload..

any Idea why and how to fix it?
I can accept other ways to play 2 or more audio files at the same time (not only WAV)

Thanks

Comment: What error does it give you?  More information is needed.

Comment: I could be wrong but a "don't send" error sounds like the type of response one might give to the Windows Error Reporting dialog that is displayed as a result of the error. In order to help you we need the message associated with the exception(s) that caused that dialog. If however a "don't send" error is something domain-specific that makes sense to folks who know DirectShow, I retract my statement and offer my appoligies for any confusion caused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WMPLib > Windows Media Player Library

add Windows Media Player reference (References > Add Reference > COM)

and use this code:

```
using WMPLib;

WindowsMediaPlayer wmp = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
wmp.URL = url; //filepath

wmp.controls.play();

wmp.settings.volume = volume; //(int between 0 to 50)

//get duration as double
WindowsMediaPlayerClass wmpi = new WindowsMediaPlayerClass();
IWMPMedia wmpinfo = wmpi.newMedia(url);
int duration = wmpinfo.duration
//end

wmp.controls.stop();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It wokrd like a charm. ~I edited your code to make it more user friendly~ Thanks again!.